# How to select number between 0 and 3.5 in regex

Tags: regex

How to select for example:

```
0
0,5
2,5
3,5
```

But not:

```
3,6
3,52
```

Comment: Could you share your input? Also some code of what have you done? Why use regex?

Comment: Usually a bad idea - just split on the whitespaces, convert it to float and compare it programatically.

Comment: www.regexr.com/48hqj

Comment: I do not know where or why you need regex for this, but what you want to do is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

In python, it's simple:

```
import re

PATTERN = re.compile(r'(?<![\d.,])([0-2]([.,]\d+)?|3([.,]([0-4]\d*|50*))?)(?![\d,.])')

number_str = input()
if PATTERN.match(number_str) is not None:
    print('Do something')
else:
    print('It\'s not a match')
```

- `[0-2]` will match the first digit and natural numbers between 0 and 2.
- `[.,]` will match the separator between the cases.
- `\d+` will match any natural number.
- `([.,]\d+)?` will match if exists, a separator followed by any natural number.

Please take a look of the following links (they may help you with regex):

1. [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module
2. [regex101](https://regex101.com/) helper

Comment: This works fine. THANKS  (?<![\d.,])([0-2]([.,]\d+)?|3([.,]([0-4]\d*|50*))?)(?![\d,.])')

Comment: it also catches the positive part of a negative number. Try "-1.4".

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible ([**demo link**](https://regex101.com/r/IJyJBu/3/)):

```
\b
(?<!-)
(?:
    (?:[0-3](?!,))
    |
    (?:[0-2],\d+)
    |
    (?:3,(?:5(?!\d)|[0-4]\d*))
)
\b
```

don't use it - convert the numbers to floats and compare them programatically.

Comment: it also catches the positive part of a negative number. Try "-1.4".

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better iterating over a list of the numbers and using list comprehension of some sort to extract what you need;

```
nums = [0, 0.5, 2.5, 3.5, 2.6, 8.4, 9.1, 7.5]

my_nums = [num for num in nums if num%0.5 == 0]

print(my_nums)

>>> [0, 0.5, 2.5, 3.5, 7.5]
```

Comment: OP might not have them in a list - that's why they were looking for a regex in the first place, I guess...